# How to determine users location with accurate like google maps do?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation

While `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` from Google Chrome on PC returns position far away about 100 meters it need to be, Google maps (also using on PC) detects it more accurately (10 meters away).
Is there any possibility to determine users location like Google maps do?

Answer (score 0):

Selective Availability phased out a while ago, so it's no longer a matter of the satellite data being degraded to protect from improvised guided missiles.

Nowadays, you're limited by the sensors you use. Many times, the environment and your consumer device will degrade accuracy. But gps hardware isn't the only sensor you have available; nearby wifi networks and other signals can be used to greatly improve your 'gps' accuracy. This is precisely how google manages to have extremely accurate user-positioning services on google maps.

So don't be afraid to use other sources of location to improve the accuracy of your location sensor (which is just `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` at the moment). `navigator.geolocation` seems to be a sensor made from information available to the browser, which alone isn't particularly accurate. Proper gps is accurate to within 8m. More information can be found on the [american website for gps](https://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/).